# 6 different random unique numbers php

Tags: php, random, numbers, unique

I have generated in an array 6 random numbers using the `rand()` function. I would like to ensure that none of these numbers are duplicates. 
I have written:

```
$lucky_numbers = array (rand (1,50), rand (1,50),rand (1,50),rand (1,50),rand (1,50),rand (1,50));
if ($lucky_numbers[0] == $lucky_numbers[1]) {
  print "same";
  $lucky_numbers[1]++;
}
if ($lucky_numbers[1] > 50) {
  $lucky_numbers[1] = $lucky_numbers[1]- 6;
}
```

and then checked each consecutive number with a similar code. But something doesn't work. Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make an array from 1 to 50. Then use `array_rand()` to pick 6 random elements from the array.

Comment: @Barmar: what if there is a duplicate?  I want 10 unique random numbers between 1 and 5.

Comment: @AbraCadaver If you make an array from 1-50 and shuffle it... how do you suppose a duplicate would exist?

Comment: How can you take 10 unique numbers between 1 and 5? There are only 5 options.

Comment: @Jon:  Good point, I misread as I am heavy in the beer.  It is Saturday.

Comment: @HugoDelsing: Exactly, there was a question last month or so wanting that.  Thought Barmar would remember.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function.

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 50);
shuffle($numbers);
for ($x=1;$x<=6;$x++){ 
  echo $numbers[$x] . "\n";
}
?>
```

See [codepad example](http://codepad.org/1CTmNWjw)

Comment: you might instead want to use `array_search` to save some memory as you arent requesting large amount of unique numbers this might be even faster as well.

Comment: `faster` and `save_memory` can only be true for large amounts of data. With 50 keys I couldn't get it slower unless I use `sleep`.

Comment: Also I have no idea what you are searching for.

Comment: True but wasting memory like this in large application eventually will end up being slower,you always need to think of ways to improve performance.        $lucky_numbers = [];
        for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
            do
                $tmp_rand = rand(1, 50);
            while(array_search($tmp_rand,$lucky_numbers));
            $lucky_numbers[] = $tmp_rand;
        }